# C# - Get HtmlDocument Content of HTML Frame

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

I am trying to develop an application that automatically retrieves data from a table located on a website. I already coded the automatic log-in and redirection to the page where the table is located.

The HtmlDocument consists of a `frameset` that contains multiple `frames`. In each of these frames a subdocument is located, which unfortunatly, doesn't show up if I read the retrieved HTML code of my application.

This is what the website code looks like:

```
<frame src="welcome.htm" scrolling="auto" name="main">
  #document
      <html>...</html>
</frame>
```

This is what my retrieved data looks like:

```
<frame src="welcome.htm" scrolling=auto name="main">
```

with nothing after it. The table I want to access is inside this `#document`.

How would I do this?

Comment: As of now how are you retrieving the HTML ? which method are you using etc ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I am using `WebBrowserInstance.DocumentText`, and I would use `WebBrowserInstance.Document.GetElementById()` to get the table element.

Comment: have you tried `WebBrowserInstance.Document.GetElementById("yourid").innerHtml;` ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa That contains an empty string. It appears the `#document` does not exist in the html file..?

Comment: If im not wrong the `DocumentText` returns a string right ? not an HTML element object, which means `GetElementById` would not work. Can you confirm

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Normally `DocumentText` should return the entire text of the HtmlDocument, but it for some reason doesn't get the `#document` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out myself. By adding the `welcome.htm` to the URL of the website you get the source document, and the elements on the page.